# Unit Testing: How to check non-constant arguments without forcing implementation

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mocking

I'm writing a unit test for a class which needs to set an alarm that will expire 24 hours from now.

I'm trying to write the test in a way which is as implementation-agnostic as possible, so that it will only break when it really fails to do its job, and not break just because the underlying implementation changes.

So I've mocked only the most basic calls to dependencies, such as getting a reference to the alarm manager, creating pending intents, etc.

However, I'm running into an issue when I try to confirm that the call to `AlarmManager.set()` is actually scheduled for 24 hours from now.  The second argument to `AlarmManager.set()` is supposed to be the time at which the alarm will expire, and of course the class under test must calculate that.  The problem is that there are multiple ways to do that (using `System.currentTimeMillis() + 24*60*60000`, or `GregorianCalendar alarmTime = new GregorianCalendar(); alarmTime.add(HOUR_OF_DAY, 24)`, or whatever.

I could try to mock the calls to one of the methods used to calculate the alarm expiration time, so that I can control and calculate a precise expectation for the time expiration argument.   But any method I mock will force a particular implementation in the real class.

I tried to get around it by allowing a fuzzy check of the alarm time - that is, using my test code to estimate the expected alarm time, then using an argument matcher with some time window to allow for execution time. This creates an obvious race condition which is undesirable.  I"m currently measuring about a 25 to 30 ms difference between the estimated alarm time and the actual alarm time.

```
long alarmTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 24*60*60000;
mMockAlarmManager.set(EasyMock.eq(AlarmManager.RTC),
                      EasyMock.and(EasyMock.geq(alarmTime), //<-- Lower Bound
                      EasyMock.leq(alarmTime+300)),         //<--Upper Bound
                      EasyMock.eq(mMockPendingIntent));
```

Of course I can play with the timewindow to make the test pass, but this feels wrong to me. In this particular case, I can set the window pretty wide and be ok, because my program doesn't care if the alarm time is exact - even a couple of minutes is ok.  But this is just a simple example of a larger problem that I'm sure I will encounter in future unit tests.  What would I do if the time needs to be more exact?  What would I do if the argument isn't a time, but something else that needs to be dynamically calculated and can be done in many different ways that should all pass the test?

Is there a better way to check that non-constant arguments are computed correctly without requiring mocks which force the class under test to use a particular implementation?

**EDIT**:

I want to be clear about the type of answer I am looking for.  Clearly, I can modify the implementation of the class under test to abstract this away or that away.  But that's modifying the class under test to make it agnostic to the test.  I'm looking for ways of writing a good unit test that tests *only the requirements* and not the implementation.

Consider the situation where the tester and developer are two distinct people, and their only point of contact is an API and a set of requirements (presume they are both written correctly, etc etc...I know the real world is often different).  How can the tester write a unit test without knowing the implementation?

So I'm looking for ways to modify the **test**, not the **class under test.**

Comment: Why don't you create a simple wrapper for time (getters and setters which use a single method for getting time; System or GregorianCalendar). When you construct an alarm, pass this time object as a parameter. This has the added advantage of decoupling the alarm code from the time source.

Answer (score 0):

If you were ready to do so, you could move the calculation of the next alarm time into a function of it's own, and in your test mock the result of that function. This way you can make sure that your function sets an alarm at the desired time. Either that or find a way to pass the current time as a parameter, as you need a way for the test to specify a constant value if the result is to be predicted exactly.

Since, with your edit, you specify that you don't want to change the code itself and only want to modify the test, having a range of acceptable values would be the way to go. Unless it is critical that a one day delay is precise to the milliseconds, having a large range of valid result is perfectly acceptable.

The important part to remember is that unit testing helps in making sure your code works according to your tests, and that it won't break in the future without someone knowing about it. If setting the alarm "one day in the future from now, give or take 5 minutes" is acceptable, then go ahead and do that, and move on to more important stuff. The gain in productivity coming from unit testing can easily be wasted by going overboard and nitpicking every small details; you must draw a line somewhere.

Comment: see OP edit.  However, your advice is sound - I may be spending too  much time on this.  But my question was prompted by a concern about more complicated situations than just calculating a time offset, and the somewhat philosophical question of isolating tests from the implementation.

Comment: @rothloup I've edited my answer, but the bottom line stays the same, I'm afraid :)

Comment: thanks for your input, I appreciate it.  I'll post if I find a better way.